# Scrollable GridView in different browsers

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have created a scrollable gridview. So I have created a table which is the copy of grid header.  I give width property to  each  with pixel. But it works different in different browsers. Any help appreciated.

[image: Here is the photo]
This is the markup of Grid header.

```
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th width="26px">
                </th>
                <th width="152px">
                    Sosial sığorta nömrəsi
                </th>
                <th width="122px">
                    Soyadı
                </th>
                <th width="121px">
                    Adı
                </th>
                <th width="120px">
                    Atasının adı
                </th>
                <th width="50px">
                    Cinsi
                </th>
                <th width="100px">
                    Doğum tarixi
                </th>
                <th width="122px">
                    Uçota düşmə tarixi
                </th>
                <th width="102px">
                    SUN (köhnə)
                </th>
                <th width="150px">
                    Sığorta edənin VÖEN-i
                </th>
                <th width="102px">
                    SUN
                </th>
                <th width="102px">
                    Ölüm tarixi
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: try specifying width to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating 2 tables, one for the header and another for the data - just create a single table...

Something like this should have all your columns in the correct width:

```
<table  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th width="26px">
            </th>
            <th width="152px">
                Sosial sığorta nömrəsi
            </th>
           .....
            <th width="102px">
                Ölüm tarixi
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Enter data here -->
        </tr>
        <tr> <!-- Enter data here -->
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Blachshma said, you can use only one table for that to fix the column width same for all browsers... And I think, Making table/grid scrollable is an easy task...

Try this..

```
<div style="max-width:500px;overflow:auto;">

    // Here, HTML code for Table or Gridview

</div>
```

Hope, it helps you. !!
Thanks.